# MVC View with foor loop only returning last item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, controller

I've got a partial view generating a list of other partial views, and when I submit to controller, I only get the data I want from the last added item. I've obviously done something silly, but I cant see what.

```
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Listofthings.Count(); i++)
    {
        <ul>
            <li>
                @{Html.RenderPartial("Thing", Model.Listofthings[i]);}
            </li>
        </ul>
}
```

And inside the Thing partial we have:

```
@model FancyObject
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('a#selectUser').click(function () {
            $('form#selectUserForm').submit();
        });
    });
```

```
< link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/Site.css" />
< form id="selectUserForm" method="post" action="@Url.Action("SelectUser", "Home")">

@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SomethingImportant)
            <a href="#" id="selectUser" class="HyperLink1">
                <i class="fa fa-female"></i>
                <span class="nav-text">
                    @Model.AProperty
                </span>
            </a>
```

Now when I submit the form, I only get the "SomethingImportant" from the last item created by the above. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd set the <ul> and </ul> tags out the @for loop. Now, you don't have a list, you have several lists with just one element each.

Comment: There are multiple issues with your code. First scripts should NEVER be in partials. Next your generating duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html and means you scripts can never work correctly. And despite what your claim, your will only ever submit the first form, not the last. Its difficult to understand what (and why) your trying to do here, especially when you do not show the controller methods.

Comment: The issue is the duplicate id tags. What I'm trying to do is have a list of objects you can click and then get information about these displayed on a different page. The partial view is a sidebar menu, and after clicking a name you see information about whatever you clicked. Scripts were never in the partial views, they were either in shared layout or the main page that rendered the partial, it was only so the scripts were visible :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the last item because the hidden field in your `Thing` partial view get the same name on every `foreach` iteration.

1. You can either grab a collection of all hidden values in your controller action by declaring parameter as a `list` or any collection.
   `public ActionResult GetMyValues(List<string> SomethingImportant)`
2. Or you can differentiate name of hidden field on every `iteration` and get them separately in your controller.